# How to create the following shape in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

[image]

I wan to create above shape in flutter. I was using clipPath for getting the sides right but i couldn't get the rounded corners.

Answer (score 3):

You must use for this shape `flutter_custom_clippers` package from [here](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_custom_clippers).
Add this dependency in your pubspec.yaml file

Try below code hope its help to you

**Import package in your file**

```
import 'package:flutter_custom_clippers/flutter_custom_clippers.dart';
```

**Your Widget:**

```
 ClipPath(
            clipper: RoundedDiagonalPathClipper(),
            child: Container(
              height: 320,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                  Radius.circular(
                    50.0,
                  ),
                ),
                color: Colors.grey[300],
              ),
              child: Center(
                child: Text("Your Shape"),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Your result screen-> [image]

Comment: without library use clippath widget

Comment: Appreciate the answer, but i am looking for doing this without any third party packages to have more control on how i make my shape as per different designs.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `CustomClipper`

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Rounded corner'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Color(0xff240046), borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12, vertical: 18),
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8),
        child: ClipPath(
          clipper: CustomRectClipper(),
          child: Container(
            height: 500,
            width: 300,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(50.0)),
              color: Colors.grey,
            ),
            child: Center(child: Text("RoundedDiagonalPathClipper()")),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomRectClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    Path path = new Path()
      ..lineTo(0.0, size.height)
      ..lineTo(size.width, size.height)
      ..lineTo(size.width, 0.0)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(size.width-50, 0.0, size.width - 60.0, -5.0)
      ..lineTo(40.0, 150.0) // here you adjust the value as much as you nee
      ..quadraticBezierTo(0.0, 180.0, 0.0, 220.0);
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: The corners here doesn't look smooth

Comment: @sumitkumarPradhan updated my answer and you adjust the value from custompath to adjust the value

Comment: This is the better answer here. No need to use a pub library for such simple task, as the other answer suggests. Smooth or not, can always be further refined and polished.