# Flutter Container with Horizontal line

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, frontend

Hi :D what is the easiest way for creating a Container in Flutter with all 4 corners rounded, a shadow (like the Material widget provides with the elevation) and one Side Diagonal or like cutted of: [image: PPP]

I drew this with PowerPoint, so sorry for that "Straight" Lines :D

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69475976/13997210) answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this out: https://fluttershapemaker.com/

It'll convert whatever svg shape you want into a CustomPainer Widget that you can use in your project.